# Image upload with s3fs and application performance

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, image-uploading, s3fs

I am developing a web application in ASP.NET 4.5. One part of the application includes the user the option to upload images. The images are stores on Amazon S3. Right now the pathc I though about choosing is to use Amazon SDK to upload the images to the bucket on S3 and server them via CloudFront. The thing is that I think that using [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) might be a better option.

If I mount an S3 bucket as a folder, when the user upload a photo, I can continue the application operation, knowing that the image will be transferred via the network to S3, so I don't need to wait until this process completes before continuing the code. So all I have to do is to wait until the image finished uploading to the server and continue the code.

I want to know if this a good way to do this. Waiting for images to upload can take time and I don't want the user to wait until all the images have been uploaded, which can take some time.

Any suggestions for the best implementation of image uploading?

Answer (score 1):

That is a suitable approach if you will be having multiple application servers which need to interact with a single bucket.  You might want to consider configuring s3fs to use a local storage directory as cache, so as to improve performance, as writing directly to your s3fs mount will typically take longer than to local storage.

Comment: IF i use it as cache, this means that the image will be written to the memory instead of the disk, but still will be send to my bucket?

Comment: No, the s3fs caching option, provide a local file system cache, not an in-memory cache.  So you could for example use your fast EC2 ephemeral storage volume to perform primary read/writes.  You would have the directory you determine to use on this volume set up as cache directory for s3fs, such that s3fs would manage the final read/write to S3 bucket.  This would give give you eventual consistency between your local cache directory and S3 as opposed to immediate consistency as you would get writing directly to s3fs mount, but for user image uploads and such, this would probably be OK.